# Angular: Mat-expansion-panel not showing all fields

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on an app with angular 8, where I want to create a form with options that a user enter inputs and by clicking on a button, it should show the created form or table. The form can be created without any issue I guess, but it doesn't show all the fields. What am I doing wrong? I tried so many scenarios like changing the html form, but none were useful. It only prints the third field, which is the 'description' field. All other fields are being escaped or not being registered. Anyone please can maybe spot the issues?

This is exercise-list.component.html file:

```html
<mat-accordion multi=true *ngIf="exercises.length > 0">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let element of exercises">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{element.workoutTitle}}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <p>{{element.name}}</p>
        <p>{{element.description}}</p>
        <p>{{element.nrSets}}</p>
        <p>{{element.nrRepsTime}}</p>

        <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-button>EDIT</button>
            <button mat-button>DELETE</button>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf="exercises.length <= 0">
    No exercise added yet
</p>
```

This is exercise-create.component.html file:

```html
<mat-card>
    <form (submit)="onAddExercise(exerciseForm)" #exerciseForm="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" ngModel required name="Workout Title" placeholder="Workout Title" #title="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Exercise</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" ngModel required name="exerciseName" #exerciseName="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="exerciseName.invalid">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput type="text" ngModel required name="description" #exerciseName="ngModel"></textarea>
            <mat-error *ngIf="exerciseName.invalid">Required.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Sets</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" ngModel required name="sets" #sets="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="sets.invalid">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Reps/Times</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="number" ngModel required name="repsTimes" #repsTimes="ngModel">
            <mat-error *ngIf="repsTimes.invalid">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <br>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Save Workout</button>

    </form>
</mat-card>
```

This is exercise-list.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Exercise } from '../../models/exercise-model';
import { ExerciseService } from '../../services/exercise.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exercise-list',
  templateUrl: './exercise-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exercise-list.component.css']
})
export class ExerciseListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  exercises: Exercise[] = [];
  private exerciseSub: Subscription;

  constructor(public exerciseService: ExerciseService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exercises = this.exerciseService.getExercises();
    this.exerciseSub = this.exerciseService.getPostUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
        this.exercises = exercises;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.exerciseSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

This is exercise-create.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { Exercise } from '../../models/exercise-model';
import { ExerciseService } from 'src/app/services/exercise.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exercise-create',
  templateUrl: './exercise-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exercise-create.component.css']
})

export class ExerciseCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public exerciseService: ExerciseService) {
  }

  onAddExercise(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) { return; }

    this.exerciseService.addExercise(
      form.value.workoutTitle,
      form.value.name,
      form.value.description,
      form.value.nrSets,
      form.value.nrRepsTime);
    form.resetForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

This is exerciseService.ts file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Exercise } from '../models/exercise-model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ExerciseService {
  private exercises: Exercise[] = [];
  private exercisesUpdatd = new Subject<Exercise[]>();

  getExercises() {
    return [...this.exercises];
  }

  getPostUpdateListener() {
    return this.exercisesUpdatd.asObservable();
  }

  addExercise(workoutTitle: string, exerciseName: string, description: string, sets: number, repsTime: string) {
    const exercise: Exercise = {
      workoutTitle: workoutTitle,
      name: exerciseName,
      description: description,
      nrSets: sets,
      nrRepsTime: repsTime
    };
    this.exercises.push(exercise);
    this.exercisesUpdatd.next([...this.exercises]);
  }
}
```

The exercise.model.ts file:

```js
export interface Exercise {
  workoutTitle: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  nrSets: number;
  nrRepsTime: string;
}
```

This is the result visually. As it can be seen, there is entered data for all the fields, but only description is being displayed. 
[image]

Here is link to the stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atf1vb

Comment: Could you print the `exercises` in `ngOnInit` of `exercise-list.component.ts`?

Comment: I used dummy data and it was working. so yes.

Comment: I think it should work. I only wonder if elements of this `exercises` have all the fields needed.

Comment: I tried different thing, but I couldn't find out where the error is.

Comment: You put your code with sample data in stackblitz?

Comment: @JuNe just added the stackBlitz link.

Comment: the stackblitz project isn't working for me